# Laravel did user liked the post efficency

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I created the following simple mechanism in order to check if the logged user liked the post of not.

I wonder if it's efficient and if there's anyway of making it better

Post Model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like');
}

public function likedByUser()
{

if (Auth::user())
        return $this->likes()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    else
        return array();
}
```

Post Controller:

```
$posts = Post::with('likedByUser')
->selectRaw('*, (score / (NOW() - posts.created_at)) as `ordering_value`')
->orderBy('ordering_value', 'DESC')
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(12);
return $posts;
```

posts.blade:

```
@if(isset($post->likedByUser[0]))
style="background-position: right;" data-value="liked"
@endif
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code review, not a specific programming question. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks good to me. And I don't think there's any way to get better performance and keep the simplicity of Eloquent relations and eager loading.

However one addition, to improve your syntax a bit...

I'd add an attribute accessor so your `@if` gets a bit prettier:

```
public function getLikedAttribute(){
    return ! $this->likedByUser->isEmpty();
}
```

And then in your view:

```
@if($post->liked)
    style="background-position: right;" data-value="liked"
@endif
```